# nginx + php5-fpm + htdocs on USB

Tags: setup, usb, server

None of the configurations that I've looked up can help with setting up Nginx to serve PHP files on a mounted USB folder. I'm currently getting `file not found` when I try and access a PHP file on the USB but PHP displays correctly when accessing it on the default folder `/usr/share/nginx/www`.

In other words, If I have a `test.php` in `/media/usb/downloads/` and try to access `sitename.com/usb/test.php` I get `file not found`. But, if i place it in `/usr/share/nginx/www/` it works. In both cases, static files work fine.

I have installed nginx and php5-fpm with defaults but added the following changes:

**nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
location /usb/ {
    alias /media/usb/downloads/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    #deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Concretely are you saying that if you attempt to access `/usb/file.php` and `/media/usb/downloads/file.php` exists, you receive `find not found`?  Are you able to access static files in the directory?

Comment: Yes... I'll update the question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the Raspberry Pi...?

Comment: I agree with @Jivings, is this a configuration that you can validate on other hardware?  I wonder if there is a conflict with `sitename.com/usb/test.php` matching both location directives.

Comment: On another note, check your logs of nginx, most of the time they contain way more information then the default error message displayed in your browser (if they are useful update your question). Else I agree with @Jivings and HeatfanJohn

Comment: Have a look at this http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,222813 I think it is your PHP declaration that is the problem. You may also want to check this serverfault question http://serverfault.com/questions/368510/nginx-fpm-php-all-php-files-say-file-not-found

Comment: Thanks. The reason it's related to Raspberry Pi is because LINUX + USB + Anything is part of Raspberry Pi learning. I agree this couold live somewhere else like: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48734/nginx-php5-fpm-htdocs-on-usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not ideal since this is circumventing ngnix configuration, using a symbolic link (ln -s) inside the default www root works. For example, using the default config and from the default www folder:

`/usr/share/nginx/www $ sudo ln -s /media/usb/downloads/ usb`

Thanks!! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48734/nginx-php5-fpm-htdocs-on-usb

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out something here.

Today, when I tried to configure nginx to serve PHP files on my Raspberry Pi Zero (Rpi0) running on Kali Linux OS, I noticed most of tutorials out there I found are mostly based on an old php5-fpm package. In my case, when I tried to install php-fpm package using *apt-get install php-fpm*, apt-get installed the newest one, i.e. php7.2-fpm package. So, I had to make sure all the nginx configuration for my virtual hosts reflect to the php7.2-fpm and not php5-fpm package as most tutorials call for.

I hope that will help you to get started.